# Compute percentage for each row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
                  country_name  country_code  val_code  \
   United States of America           231                     1   
   United States of America           231                     2   
   United States of America           231                     3   
   United States of America           231                     4   
   United States of America           231                     5   

      y191      y192      y193      y194      y195  \
   47052179  43361966  42736682  43196916  41751928   
   1187385   1201557   1172941   1176366   1192173   
   28211467  27668273  29742374  27543836  28104317   
   179000    193000    233338    276639    249688   
   12613922  12864425  13240395  14106139  15642337
```

In the data frame above, I would like to compute for each row, the percentage of the total occupied by that val_code, resulting in foll. data frame.

I.e. Sum up each row and divide by total of all rows

```
                  country_name  country_code  val_code  \
   United States of America           231                     1   
   United States of America           231                     2   
   United States of America           231                     3   
   United States of America           231                     4   
   United States of America           231                     5  

      perc   
  50.14947129
  1.363631254
  32.48344744
  0.260213146
  15.74323688
```

Right now, I am doing this, but it is not working

```
grp_df = df.groupby(['country_name', 'val_code']).agg()

pct_df = grp_df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: 100*x/float(x.sum()))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ge the total for all the columns of interest and then add the percentage column:

```
In [35]:
total = np.sum(df.ix[:,'y191':].values)
df['percent'] = df.ix[:,'y191':].sum(axis=1)/total * 100
df

Out[35]:
               country_name  country_code  val_code      y191      y192  \
0  United States of America           231         1  47052179  43361966   
1  United States of America           231         1   1187385   1201557   
2  United States of America           231         1  28211467  27668273   
3  United States of America           231         1    179000    193000   
4  United States of America           231         1  12613922  12864425   

       y193      y194      y195    percent  
0  42736682  43196916  41751928  50.149471  
1   1172941   1176366   1192173   1.363631  
2  29742374  27543836  28104317  32.483447  
3    233338    276639    249688   0.260213  
4  13240395  14106139  15642337  15.743237
```

So `np.sum` will sum all the values:

```
In [32]:
total = np.sum(df.ix[:,'y191':].values)
total

Out[32]:
434899243
```

We then call `.sum(axis=1)/total * 100` on the cols of interest to sum row-wise, divide by the total and multiply by 100 to get a percentage.

Answer (score 17):

You can get the percentages of each column using a `lambda` function as follows:

```
>>> df.iloc[:, 3:].apply(lambda x: x / x.sum())
       y191      y192      y193      y194      y195
0  0.527231  0.508411  0.490517  0.500544  0.480236
1  0.013305  0.014088  0.013463  0.013631  0.013713
2  0.316116  0.324405  0.341373  0.319164  0.323259
3  0.002006  0.002263  0.002678  0.003206  0.002872
4  0.141342  0.150833  0.151969  0.163455  0.179920
```

Your example does not have any duplicate values for `val_code`, so I'm unsure how you want your data to appear (i.e. show percent of total in column vs. total for each v`val_code` group.)

Comment: how to use the same technique to x/x.sum(axis=1) (that is percentage across row total). thanks. i need it for some other task.

Comment: wow that was quick. actually i just solved the problem from other posting..  df.apply(lambda x: x/x.sum(), axis=1) (just needed to add axis=1 to apply). in any case thank you so much.. your reply to this question was the lead to exactly what i wanted. previously i was trying the axis=1 parameter in wrong position.