# How to convert survey results as a percentage of the total respondents in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

A survey was conducted with `2,233` respondents and the following results came under the following columns, `Very interested`,  `Somewhat interested` and `Not interested` as seen below

```
                    Very interested  Somewhat interested  Not interested 

A.                        1688,                444,               60,

B                         1629,                477,               74,

C                         1340,                734,              102,

D                         1332,                729,               127, 

E                         1263,                770,               136,
```

How can I convert these numbers into percentages of the total number of respondents which is 2,233 and round of the percentages to 2 decimal places?

Comment: Thanks Mike for editing. It looks better

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compute percentage for each row in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31481803/compute-percentage-for-each-row-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

Using your sample data, I removed the commas so that I could convert it to an int, then swapped the real values with percentages:

```
for col in list(df):
    df[col] = df[col].str.replace(',','')
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col])

(100. * df / 2233).round(2)
```

Output:

```
    Very interested     Somewhat interested     Not interested
A.  75.59                  19.88                    2.69
B   72.95                  21.36                    3.31
C   60.01                  32.87                    4.57
D   59.65                  32.65                    5.69
E   56.56                  34.48                    6.09
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to mark as correct if it's settled

Comment: Hi, Josh. Please could you do away with the str commands. I have just been trying the codes but I have been getting error messages since then. Could it be because there is really no string parameters to replace in my own data? Thanks

Comment: Am really new in this, my data is .csv file. Please don't use excel and please writ the codes knowing there is no string. Thanks

Comment: Using the code above, am getting this error message : Unable to parse string Data/Analysis /Statistics " at position 0. Please what am I not doing right

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I Just wrote a little excel file with your provided data and it worked:

I used following excel file:

```
        Very Interested        Somewhat Interested        Not Interested

A           1688                       444                      60

B           1629                       477                      74

C           1340                       734                     102

D           1332                       729                     127
```

And the code:

```
df = pandas.read_excel('./test.xlsx', sep=',', delimiter=None)
df = df.astype(float)
df = (100. * df/2233).round(2)
```

So first im loading my excel file and making it to a pandas Dataframe then im casting all the integers to floats so when storing your 2 point float the decimals wont be cut off.. Then iterating over all indexes and columns making the math and storing it at the right position. Then it's done. Worked for me

And if you want to save your dataframe back to an excel file you can do that like this:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output-in-percent.xlsx')
test.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Comment: btw i would appreciate if someone more skilled in python and pandas would correct my attempt.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I have tried it out and it did not work

Comment: Thank you very much for the attempt. I have also tried it but it didn't work

Comment: It's exactly as it is above the only thing is that I added the commas ie , to all the figures to make them stay in columns.  The commas  as in 1688, it reads actually 1688  and so others. So no ,

Comment: I Edited my post.

Comment: Hey Christoph. Nothing wrong with your answer, but a good rule of thumb in Pandas is you should hardly ever need to loop through your df. Pandas is much faster because it can do vectorised operations (acting on the whole df together).

Comment: yeah looked amazed at your code and edited mine quickly. Thanks for that. gotta get used to python that would make a lot of tasks much easier.

Comment: @ChristophPelzer no problem! Pandas has its own flavour, more similar to R or MATLAB than Python imo. Also, not much point in editing your post to be the same as mine :)

Comment: @JoshFriedlander That is right but i wanted to merge our efforts since you iterated over a list and with your advice there is no loop necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I believe the code below will be helpful.

```
df=(df/2233).style.format("{:.2%}")
```

[image: The result]

Answer (score -1):

```
df = df.astype(float)
df = (df/2233).round(2)
```

Comment: answer requires to context to prevent removal.