# Change each cell in a pandas data frame to percentages

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, percentage

I have a dataset that reads 13 csv files per column. Each row represents clusters (4 total) and the data reflects the frequency that each file appears in each of those clusters. My questions is how do I convert each cell into percentages? This is how my data frame looks like right now:

[image]

This is what I would like it to look like:

```
row_0    001.csv    002.csv    003.csv    004.csv   005.csv
0        0%         0.35%
1        86.08%     0%
2        0.07%      0%
3        0.06%      1.24%
```

Each value in each cell is out of 10,000.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compute percentage for each row in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31481803/compute-percentage-for-each-row-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your total is `10000`, you can just divide by `100` and format:

```
# random data
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([2345, 123, 6789], 
                                   size=(5,5))
                 )
df.div(100).astype('str').add('%')
```

Output:

```
        0       1       2       3       4
0   1.23%  23.45%  23.45%   1.23%   1.23%
1  23.45%  23.45%   1.23%  23.45%   1.23%
2  23.45%  67.89%   1.23%  67.89%  23.45%
3  67.89%   1.23%  67.89%  23.45%  23.45%
4  67.89%  23.45%   1.23%  67.89%  67.89%
```